# Depth First Search without stack

Tags: c#, depth-first-search

I started to code with stack as:

```
void Foo(TreeNode root)
    {
        Stack nodes = new Stack();
        nodes.Push(root);

        while (nodes.Count > 0)
        {
            TreeNode node = (TreeNode) nodes.Pop();
            Console.WriteLine(node.Text);
            for (int i = node.Nodes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                nodes.Push(node.Nodes[i]);
        }
    }
```

But, without stack I do not know, what I should be doing.

I tried this. Is it correct ?
Can anyone suggest me.

```
void Foo(TreeNode root)
{
   if(root == null) return;

    System.out.print(root.Value + "\t");
    root.state = State.Visited;

    //for every child
    for(Node n: root.getChild())
    {
        //if childs state is not visited then recurse
        if(n.state == State.Unvisited)
        {
            dfs(n);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What specific issue are you having? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for assistance.

Comment: And, please remind an old guy what "DFS" means in this context?

Comment: Yes, and you just posted some Java code...

Comment: @JohnSaunders i am fine. is logic correct ?

Comment: @Josh: Actually, that's a depth-first _traversal_. It's not a search unless you stop traversing as soon as you find what you're looking for.

Comment: We are missing a lot of context there. What is the data structure you're working with? Why don't you want to use a stack? Do you need to make an iterative algorithm or is a recursive one ok? Is your data a tree or a graph? Lots and lots of questions...

Comment: @JohnSaunders Yes, that's correct. My definition was inaccurate. I think the OP wants to search but for simplicity showed a traversal. In other way the title is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
Console.WriteLine(node.Text);
for (Int i = 0; i < node.Nodes.Count; i++)
    Foo(root.Nodes[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public class Tree
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }

        public List<Tree> TreeNode
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public Tree()
        {
            this.TreeNode = new List<Tree>();
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Program pro = new Program();
            Tree tree = new Tree();
            tree.TreeNode.Add(new Tree() { Value = 1 });
            tree.TreeNode.Add(new Tree() { Value = 2 });
            tree.TreeNode.Add(new Tree() { Value = 3 });
            tree.TreeNode.Add(new Tree() { Value = 4 });
            pro.DepthFirstSearch(2, tree);
        }

        private Tree DepthFirstSearch(int searchValue, Tree root)
        {
            if (searchValue == root.Value)
            {
                return root;
            }

            Tree treeFound = null;
            foreach (var tree in root.TreeNode)
            {
                treeFound = DepthFirstSearch(searchValue, tree);
                if (treeFound != null)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            return treeFound;

        }
    }
}
```